# Equivalence between notions of dynamical coupling as defined by Villani in his book Optimal Transportation: Old and New

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator\law{law}$In Villani's book he presents the following notions of dynamical couplings:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a Polish space. A dynamical transference plan $\Pi$ is a probability measure on the space $C([0,1]; X)$. A dynamical coupling of two probabilities measures $\mu_0$, $\mu_1 \in P(X)$ is a random curve $\gamma : [0,1]\to X$ such that $\law (\gamma_0) = \mu_0$, $\law(\gamma_1) = \mu_1$.

If I'm not mistaken, I understood the "random curve" part as being equivalent to the following sentence:

There exist a measure space $(\Omega, \mathbb{P})$ measurable map $\gamma : [0,1]\times \Omega \to X$ such that  $\gamma$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ and $(e_i\circ\gamma)_*(\mathbb{P}) = \mu_i$, $i = 0,1$, where $e_t$ is the evaluation map.

Trying to see on other references, this definition based on random curves seems to be unique to his book. It appears to be much more common the use of the probability $\Pi$ as the usual notion of coupling, and using the evaluation map $e_t$ on curves as the so defined "random curve". My problem is that, when I tried to see the equivalence between these definition on his book, I went into problems as you can read below.

We have the usual notion of coupling of measures as:

> Couplings by means of random elements: Let $(E_i, \mu_i)_{i\in I}$ be a family of measures spaces, where $I$ is an index set. A coupling of the measures $\mu_i$ is a family of random elements $X_i : (\Omega, \mathbb{P}) \to E_i$ such that $(X_i)_*(\mathbb{P}) = \mu_i$.

> Couplings by means of the product space: Let $(E_i, \mu_i)_{i\in I}$ as before, with $\mathcal{A}_i$ being the $\sigma$-algebra of $E_i$. A coupling of the measures is a measure $\pi$ in the product space $(\prod_{i\in I}E_i, \bigotimes_{i\in I} \mathcal{A}_i)$, such that $(proj_i)_*(\pi) = \mu_i$, where $proj_i$ is the projection in $E_i$, and $\bigotimes_{i\in I} \mathcal{A}_i$ is the analogous to the product topology, but for $\sigma$-algebras.

It can be shown that these two definition are equivalent by taking the map $\Gamma : (\Omega,\mathbb{P}) \to (\prod_{i\in I}E_i, \bigotimes_{i\in I} \mathcal{A}_i)$, $\Gamma(\omega) = (X_i(\omega))_{i \in I}$ and defining $\pi : = \gamma_*(\mathbb{P})$. (The other way is trivial)

I want to prove something similar for the case of dynamical couplings. We can follow the same construction above and take the interval $[0,1]$ as the index set $I$. This way we obtain the map $\Gamma(\omega) : = e_\omega(\gamma)$, where $e_\omega$ is the evaluation on the second coordinate. It's clear that the image of $\Gamma$ lies in $C(I,X)$. The problem is to show that $\Gamma$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{B}(C(I,X))$ (with respect to the uniform topology). We just have the measurability of with repect to $\bigotimes_{t\in I} (\mathcal{B}(X))$.

So, how to conclude? Did I do anything wrong here? Alternatives ways are also welcomed.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What concrete example do you have in mind? $\mu_0$ the law of $(W_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ a standard Brownian motion, $\mu_1$ the law of $(B_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ a standard Brownian bridge, and for instance $\gamma_u(t) = W_t - ut W_1$ or $\tilde\gamma_u(t) = W_t - u^2t W_1$ for each $u,t\in[0,1]$? I don't think the definition of dynamical couplings you gave require anyting for $u\notin I$ for $I=\{0,1\}$, i.e., marginals only need to be correct at the two boundary points. In between, you are free to choose how to get from $\mu_0$ to $\mu_1$. Both $\gamma,\tilde\gamma$ appear to satisfy the requirements.

Comment: You should understand a random curve as a random variable with values in $C([0,1];X)$, i.e., a measurable function $\gamma\colon (\Omega,\mathbb P)\to C([0,1];X)$. In this case the correspondence between dynamical transference plans and dynamical couplings works exactly as in the usual, static case: Simply let $\Pi=\gamma_\ast(\mathbb P)$.

Comment: @MaoWao This seems to be the case. I checked the results on his book using your definitions and everything seems to work fine. Thank you very much!